# JVM heap keeps Increasing. why?

Tags: java, jdbc, memory-leaks, resources, try-with-resources

```
executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
Runnable helloRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        controller2.GetAIntFromDatabase(columblName);
    }
};
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(helloRunnable, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

this part of the program generates the increasing heap memory error.

```
 controller2.GetAIntFromDatabase(columblName);
```

with this function I read an int value from my database.

```
    @Override
    public int GetAIntFromDatabase(String columblName) {
        int stare = 0;
        try{
            String query = "SELECT * FROM stari ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"; 
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.connnection.prepareStatement(query);          
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()){
               stare = resultSet.getInt(columblName);
             preparedStatement.close();            
                resultSet.close();
               return stare;
            }
            preparedStatement.close();            
            resultSet.close();
        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("GetUtilajStare Error: "  + ex);
            return 0;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

That's the Java heap memory usage after 10 minutes of running:

[image: used Java Heap memory for 10 min]

Why does my heap memory keep increasing?

Comment: If you're new to Java, you really shouldn't be worrying about memory use. Unless you start to run out of memory.

Comment: I run out if a wait more then 2-3hour and this project needs to work 24/24

Comment: What does it say when it runs out of memory? Your `GetAIntFromDatabase` method is pretty shoddy, you should look at how others have written similar code.

Comment: I would recommend you use a profilling tool in order to see where you Heap memory is being assigned to. You can use Java Mission Control : 
https://blog.takipi.com/oracle-java-mission-control-the-ultimate-guide/

Comment: If you fail within the try block, the result set and statement will never get closed. Might be a reason for a memory leak. Try to go with try-with-resource or close the two in the catch block (which requires you to define them outside the try and perform null checks).

Comment: 2 additional side notes regarding the code : 
1. I'd suggest using a static final for your string containing the query.
2. I'd suggest using the try-with-resources on your closable cariables in the try scope - if an exception is thrown they will not be closed.... could cause a memory leak...
@Korashen - great minds buddy :)

Comment: sorry my question is wrong i will create an other one.  thank you for your time.

Comment: @lehel no need to create a new question. We can work on your problem within this question, that's totally fine.

Comment: thenx for the suggestion you guys are you guys are really amazing.

Comment: Either your program is needing more and more memory, or it is holding on to objects it no longer needs. The latter is called a memory leak. Loads have been written about how to fight such, just go search.

Comment: I modified my  GetAIntFromDatabase() like you suggested and the problem is solved. Thank you  Korashen and  Rann Lifshitz :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a Java 7+ way of closing the resources, [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

> The try-with-resources statement is a `try` statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that implements `AutoCloseable`, which includes all objects which implement `Closeable`, can be used as a resource.

```java
public int GetAIntFromDatabase(String columblName) {
    final String query = "SELECT * FROM stari ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    try (final PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.connnection.prepareStatement(query)) {
        final ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            return resultSet.getInt(columblName);
        }
        return 0;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // Do something better than System.out.println(...)
        return 0;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Also you do not have to explicitly close the result set, the prepared statement does it as it [owns the result set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close--):

> When a `Statement` object is closed, its current `ResultSet` object, if one exists, is also closed.

However, if you want to be paranoid and overkill it, as @MarkRotteveel suggests in his comment, you may add as an `AutoCloseable` resource also the `ResultSet`, and the code would then look like this:

```java
public int GetAIntFromDatabase(String columblName) {
    final String query = "SELECT * FROM stari ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    try (final PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.connnection.prepareStatement(query);
         final ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()
    ) {
    ...
}
```

I have never done it and never needed it and the documentation explicitly states that it's *not* necessary, but some people have experienced problems in certain edge cases.

In this second case it's especially visible how much the try-with-resources saves you from - you do not need to assign the variables to `null`, you do not have to check if any of them have been opened, and even if one of the `close()` methods throws an exception, the "closing chain" is not broken and the  `close()` methods of the other resources are called in any case.

Comment: It would be better to include the result set in the try-with-resources as well. Yes, by specification it is not necessary, but it is better to do it anyway.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have also heard this, but why? Isn't it just overkill? https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Tank_Bunny_Death.jpg

Comment: Yes, it looks like overkill, and should be overkill, but it is mostly to avoid unwanted behavior caused by bugs in a driver, connection pool or statement pool. Especially with statement pooling, closing a statement does not really close the statement, so it might also accidentally not close the result set until (much) later. For the most part it is paranoia and just CYA, until it bites you and you wished you had done it ;).

Answer (score 2):

If an exception is thrown after opening the  `preparedStatement` and the `resultSet`, they will never be closed. Therefore you should use the `finally` block which will always be executed.

```
public int GetAIntFromDatabase(String columblName) {
    int stare = 0;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM stari ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        preparedStatement = this.connnection.prepareStatement(query);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            stare = resultSet.getInt(columblName);
            return stare;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("GetUtilajStare Error: " + ex);
        return 0;
    } finally {
        if (preparedStatement != null)
            preparedStatement.close();
        if (resultSet != null) 
            resultSet.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would be better (and shorter!) with try-with-resources, also note that you are closing result set and statement in the wrong order (something which try-with-resources would do correct).

Comment: Commenting so I find this later

Comment: @NoelMurphy For remembering questions and/or answers, there is a feature *favorite questions*. Just click on the star on the left top of the question. You will find all the questions you marked so in your profile, tab "favorite".